# Empty objects in separate file

Tags: javascript

I have a couple JavaScript files that I am testing with before pushing to production, these files are a LocalStorage file, and a GlobalMethods file.

LocalStorage puts stuff into localstorage so I can access values, or objects etc whenever I need to.

GlobalMethods is as it sounds, a bunch of methods that are global throughout the project.

So I am having this idea that I want to have a separate file to hold empty objects that I can access and populate then throw them into storage. The only problem is that I am not a JavaScript guru and not sure how to go about doing this and what would be the best way to do it. Sure I could just make up the object where it would be being used, but then if I wanted to reuse it in another file then I would have to write it again in, and that's not good because then I would be going against DRY principles and its more work than needed.

Some examples of empty objects would be something like..

```
var obj1 = {
    FirstName: "",
    LastName: ""
};

var obj2 = {
    Line1: "",
    Line2: ""
}
```

Maybe its just as simple as that? I would like to be able to access them something like this..

> UsableObjects.obj1

or maybe something like this

> UsableObjects.Object.obj1

Thats kinda how I access values and stuff in my LocalStorage file

Any idea's or direction would be appreciated.

Comment: @Taplar, I have actually put objects into localStorage and have no issue accessing them and its contents. I want to have an external file containing just objects that I can access from any other script file

Comment: @Taplar,
var myObject = { FirstName: "Joe", LastName: "Smith" } <- is what I put into storage and can access the values like this var myOtherObject = MyStorage.Keys.TestString;
console.log(myOtherObject.FirstName);

Comment: function MyStorage() { };
MyStorage.Keys = { TestString: "" };

MyStorage.Keys = function (value) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.Keys.TestString, value)
    return value;
};

<-- Thats my localStorage

Comment: @Taplar, I think we are going off course here, this isnt about localStorage, this is about placing empty objects into a seperate file and calling them and populating the objects from any other external script file, so I dont violate DRY principals

Comment: When talking about localStorage, you should be clear if you are talking about something that is not the default localStorage.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage  In regards to sharing objects between files, if they are all on the same page and the variables are scoped high enough all scripts on the page can access them.  If you are editing the objects and want the changes to persist between page loads, you will have to persist the changes, which is where the localStorage came into the discussion.

Comment: @Taplar, I understand about accessing objects from other scripts, i was looking for a different way to do it where its like namespacing or use of classes like in C#...Ah ok, gotcha about the localStorage path, my apologies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it figured out...

```
var UsableObjects = {
    Person: function (a, b) {
        var self = this;
        var person = {
            FirstName: a,
            LastName: b
        };
        self.ShowMyPerson(person);
    },
    ShowMyPerson: function(mystring) {
        return mystring;
    }
}
```